# Increasing the performance of a code snippet with nested for-loops

Tags: python, performance, numpy, for-loop

I have to run the snippet shown below about 200000 times in a row and the snippet needs about 0.12585 seconds for 1000 iterations. Datapoints has a shape of (3, 2704, 64)

```py
    output = []
    maxium = 0
    for datapoint in datapoints:
        tmp = []
        for data in datapoint:
            maxium = max(data)
            if maxium == 0:
                tmp.append(data)
            else:
                tmp.append(data / maxium)
        output.append(tmp)
```

I have tried to rewrite it using map() but this gives me an average of 0.23237 seconds per iteration. This is probably due to the multiple max(y) and list() calls.

```py
np.asarray(list(map(lambda datapoint: list(map(lambda data: data / max(data) if max(data) > 0 else y, datapoint)), datapoints)))
```

Is there a possibility to optimize the code again to improve performance?

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment so yours doesn't make much sense now! After I posed it I noticed your use of `np.asarray`. I've added the numpy tag because the solution will certainly involved numpy's vectorised operations rather than Python for loops or `map()`.

Comment: I expect the solution to involve the [`numpy.amax()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
maximum = datapoints.max(axis=2, keepdims=True)
output = np.where(maximum==0, datapoints, datapoints/maximum)
```

You would see a warning `invalid value encounter in true_divide` but it should work as expected.

---

**Update** as @ArthurTacca pointed out:

```
output = datapoints/np.where(maximum==0, 1, maximum)
```

will eliminate the warning.

Comment: Seems like you might as well change second line to `datapoints / np.where(maximum==0, 1, maximum)` to avoid the error.

Answer (score 3):

Well here's a short answer:

```
def bar(datapoints):
    m = np.amax(datapoints, axis=2)
    m[m == 0] = 1
    return datapoints / m[:,:,np.newaxis]
```

Here's an explanation of how you might have got there (it's how I *did* get there!):

Let's start off with some example data:

```
>>> x = np.array([[[1, 2, 3, 4], [11, -12, 13, -14]], [[26, 27, 28, 29], [0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Now check what you get on your original function:

```
def foo(datapoints):
    output = []
    maxium = 0
    for datapoint in datapoints:
        tmp = []
        for data in datapoint:
            maxium = max(data)
            if maxium == 0:
                tmp.append(data)
            else:
                tmp.append(data / maxium)
        output.append(tmp)
    return numpy.array(output)
```

The result is:

```
>>> foo(x)
array([[[ 0.25      ,  0.5       ,  0.75      ,  1.        ],
        [ 0.84615385, -0.92307692,  1.        , -1.07692308]],

       [[ 0.89655172,  0.93103448,  0.96551724,  1.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]]])
```

Now let's try out amax:

```
>>> np.amax(x, axis=0)
array([[26, 27, 28, 29],
       [11,  0, 13,  0]])
>>> np.amax(x, axis=2)
array([[ 4, 13],
       [29,  0]])
```

Ah ha, looks like `axis=2` is what we're after. Now we want to divide the original array by this, but only in the places where the max is non-zero. How do only divide in some places? The answer is: we divide everywhere, but in some places we divide by 1 so it has no effect. So let's replace zeros with ones:

```
>>> m = np.amax(x, axis=2)
>>> m[m == 0] = 1
>>> m
array([[ 4, 13],
       [29,  1]])
```

Finally, let's divide by this, [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) back over axis 2 which we took the maximum over earlier:

```
>>> x / m[:,:,np.newaxis]
array([[[ 0.25      ,  0.5       ,  0.75      ,  1.        ],
        [ 0.84615385, -0.92307692,  1.        , -1.07692308]],

       [[ 0.89655172,  0.93103448,  0.96551724,  1.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]]])
```

Putting that all together you get `bar()` at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can definitely speed this up w/ vectorized numpy operations. Here's how I would do it, if I understand what you're trying to do correctly:

```py
import numpy as np

# I use a randomly initialized array here, replace this with your input
arr = np.random.random(size=(3, 2704, 64))

# Find max for 3rd dimension, returns array w/ shape (3, 2704)
max_arr = np.max(arr, axis=2) 

# Set up divisor, returns array w/ shape (3, 2704)
divisor = np.where(max_arr == 0, 1, max_arr)

# Use expand_dims to add third dimension, returns array w/ shape (3, 2704, 1)
divisor = np.expand_dims(divisor, axis=2)

# Perform division, shape is (3, 2704, 64)
ans = np.divide(arr, divisor)
```

From your code, I gather that you intend to scale your data by the max of your 3rd axis, but in the event of there being 0, forego scaling instead. You seem to also want your output to have the same shape as your input, which explains the way you structured `output` and `tmp`. That's why I left the code snippet to end w/ output in a numpy array, but if you need it in its original form regardless, its a simple loop to re-arrange your data:

```py
output = []
for i in ans:
    tmp = []
    for j in i:
        tmp.append(list(j))
    output.append(tmp)
```

For future reference, furnish your questions with more detail. It will make it easier for people to participate, and you'll increase the chance of getting your questions answered quickly!

Comment: I think for the last part you could use `ans.tolist()`